# how to fix request time out while indexing a dictionary

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to index my data in elastic and i get the time out error.

so i have tried changing the port and i have tried increasing the timeout. Also i have tried converting the data into json.

data is a python dict:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])


def index_profile(data):
    es.index(index='prof', id=data["id"], doc_type='people', body=data, request_timeout=30)
```

this is the network and discovery part of my elastic config file:

```
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: localhost
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: ["localhost", "[::1]"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
```

in the end i am getting this error:
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=30))
and this was in the elastic logs:
this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped

Answer (score 0):

if it helps anyone I figured out i needed to add this line to my .yml file

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
```